# Galaxy S2 not showing in Eclipse Mac

Tags: android, eclipse, device

I have been using my Galaxy S2 for testing my applications with Eclipse for a while now. All of a sudden when I try to run my applications my device does not show in the Device List of Eclipse.

I have looked everywhere on the internet for a solution, I have made sure my phone is in Debugging mode, Re-installed the SDK, restarted my computer and phone but nothing seems to be working.

I would really appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: Try changing usb port, take battery out of mobile, restart comp, restart eclipse, check if it is connected in device monitor, reinstal phone drivers.

Answer (score 1):

So after a few days of fustration and going crazy I finally worked out the problem... the usb cable. I used a different one and it worked with no problems!

I just thought I would post this in case anyone else has the same problem.